# Is there a way to bypass device DND from application installed on work profile?

Tags: android, android-permissions, mdm, do-not-disturb

Before it has been possible to give permission for bypassing device DND mode for an application in work profile by instructing user to install the same application to their personal profile as well and then change the permissions. Now that seems to be disabled or patched for atleast Samsung devices.

Found the same issue is being investigated by several tickets, e.g.:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77939714

  - Here Google developers have stated that its intended behaviour, but the steps explained above still worked.
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS

  - States too that by passing is prohibited from work profile
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/OPSGENIE-1110?focusedCommentId=3240437&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-3240437

  - Rather fresh thread about the same issue

I can reproduce issue with Googles Test DPC application, where you can create "local mdm" solution and create work profile where to install said application.

I was excepting to find a way to allow bypassing DND settings for my application in work profile. Didn't find one though.

More about Test DPC:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afwsamples.testdpc&hl=en&gl=US
- https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#testing_apps

EDIT: Seems to be impossible with any Android 13 device